# Using left outer join in this query, confused, not sure I did the right way

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, left-join

```
EMPLOYEE (fname, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)
KEY: ssn

DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
KEY: dnumber.

PROJECT (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)
KEY: pnumber.

WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)
KEY: (essn, pno)

DEPENDENT (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)
KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want to find out the last name, first name and ssn of all female managers who worked less than 5 projects and located in Detroit.

I have this so far:

```
select lname
from employee e, department d
where (e.ssn = d.mgrssn) 
and  ssn in  (
                       select  w.essn
                       from   works_on w, project p
                       left join w.pno = p.pnumber
                       and  p.plocation = 'Detroit'
                       group by w.essn
                       having count(*) <= 5
                     )
```

I'm not sure about my left join commands, did I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use a comma in a `FROM` clause.

Your query would be properly written as:

```
select lname
from employee e join
     department d
     on e.ssn = d.mgrssn and
where e.ssn in  (select  w.essn
                 from works_on w left join
                      project p
                      on w.pno = p.pnumber and  p.plocation = 'Detroit'
                 group by w.essn
                 having count(*) <= 5
                );
```

Note:  this is a syntactic statement about your query, not about the logic and what it does.

Comment: Thank you so much, also if want to change to outer join, do I just replace left join to outer join?

Comment: @Stevemccain . . . There is no such thing as a plain `outer join`.  You can use `full outer join`.  `left outer join` is the same as `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard without seeing data, I 100% agree with not using commas, I also am not sure why you want to use a left join with this as you would only get the results that satisfied the conditions you laid out anyway. You have no need to preserve null values in this scenario as far as I can tell. You may need to clarify slightly more as to why you need a left join, I added them in this anyway just because.

```
SELECT lname,
   fname,
   ssn
FROM Employee
WHERE SEX = 'F'
AND SSN IN( 
          SELECT mgrssn
          FROM department d
               LEFT JOIN works_on w ON d.mgrssn = w.essn
               LEFT JOIN project p ON p.pnumber = w.pno
          WHERE p.plocation = 'Detroit'
          GROUP BY w.essn
          HAVING COUNT(*) < 5 );
```

Comment: Hey I'm sorry but I think I posed the question wrong,  I want use outer join instead, can you write an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is an OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN is the same as writing LEFT OUTER JOIN. Are you meaning a FULL JOIN AKA FULL OUTER JOIN?

Which one you want depends on what you want to be achieved, if you want to preserve values from all tables involved, you would wan to use FULL JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN (samething) if you want a specific tables values returned you would use right or left depending on where it ends up in your query. Here is a link to a diagram which may help.

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)